# android app crashes after applying code for offline image viewing via okhhtp ,picasso

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, picasso, okhttp

I am creating a blog kind of app, which has blog title, description and image.The title and description synchronises offline perfectly via firebase .

But after applying for offline image view in my android app via **okhttp** through **picasso** in my android app (**using firebase**) the app crashes on first launch.The dependencies had been added in bulid.gradle file.

The code below, is pasted in my startactivity (it is a splash screen).

```
  FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);

                Picasso.Builder builder = new Picasso.Builder(this);
                builder.downloader(new OkHttpDownloader(this,Integer.MAX_VALUE));
                Picasso built = builder.build();
                built.setIndicatorsEnabled(false);
                built.setLoggingEnabled(true);
                Picasso.setSingletonInstance(built);
```

The error log:

```
03-02 13:04:15.325 2362-2362/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                             Process: com.dest.ola, PID: 2362
                                             java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/squareup/okhttp/OkHttpClient;
                                                 at com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader.defaultOkHttpClient(OkHttpDownloader.java:31)
                                                 at com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader.<init>(OkHttpDownloader.java:76)
                                                 at com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader.<init>(OkHttpDownloader.java:65)
                                                 at com.destiny.offrruu.StartActivity.onCreate(StartActivity.java:33)
                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2332)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2442)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1351)
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:945)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:740)
                                              Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.dest.ola-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
                                                 at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
                                                 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
                                                 at com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader.defaultOkHttpClient(OkHttpDownloader.java:31) 
                                                 at com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader.<init>(OkHttpDownloader.java:76) 
                                                 at com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader.<init>(OkHttpDownloader.java:65) 
                                                 at com.destiny.offrruu.StartActivity.onCreate(StartActivity.java:33) 
                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990) 
                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2332) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2442) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1351) 
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371) 
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:945) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:740) 
                                                Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient
                                                 at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
                                                 at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
                                                 at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
                                                 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
                                                        ... 18 more
                                              Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

This is the gradlw file for dependencies :

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.1.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.0.1'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.6.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.11.0'}
```

I had google a little and fond that the "L" (Lcom) in the below code makes android confuse.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/squareup/okhttp/OkHttpClient;
```

Please let me know the solution to it.

Comment: your log says 'Didn't find class "com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient'. Are you sure you have imported okhttp library correctly ?

Comment: can you post both your build.gradle files? may be you didnt add dependencies or jars.

Comment: i had added the dependencies.

Comment: yes. post your build.gradle file code.

Comment: Try updating your build tools version. I'm sure this is build issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well This is not an appropriate solution but it seems that there is some bug in okhttp library.

To solve this error i just replaced my gradle with the **older version of okhttp**

```
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
```

instead of

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.6.0'
```

And it works like a charm.
Thankyou.